# There are weird spaces between div and div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a menu of the pizzas.
and I found a little space between div and div.
I think there is a problem with position:relative.
When I change relative to absolute, it's okay.
but if I use relative. there are spaces.
I really need your help.
I wrote a comment at where I found the problem.
Please check.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(209, 209, 209);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.title-container {}

.title-container h1 {
  color: #d35400;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
}

.title-container h4 {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)
}

.item-box1 {
  margin: .7em;
  width: 25em;
  height: 13em;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-box1 h1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 80%;
  left: 10%;
}

.item-box1 h4 {
  bottom: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 49%;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}

.image {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 11%;
  left: -25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title-container" class="title-container">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi id amet sit pariatur nemo cupiditate earum <br>numquam hic qui ratione molestias molestiae tempore placeat, libero neque odio <br> vero officiis ad?</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="item-box-container" class="item-box-container">
    <div>
      <!--This div-->
      <div id="item-box" class="item-box1">
        <img class="image" src="https://photos.bigoven.com/recipe/hero/baked-potato-pizza-8.jpg?h=500&w=500" alt="">
        <h1>Potato</h1>
        <h4>Includes potato, tomato,<br> cheese.</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="item-box" class="item-box1">
        <img class="image" src="https://photos.bigoven.com/recipe/hero/baked-potato-pizza-8.jpg?h=500&w=500" alt="">
        <h1>Potato</h1>
        <h4>Includes potato, tomato,<br> cheese.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!--And this div-->
      <div id="item-box" class="item-box1">

      </div>
      <div id="item-box" class="item-box1">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need your help.

Comment: vertical-align:top to your inline-block element

Answer (score -1):

This space appears because the "item-box1" class has CSS "height: 13em". Removing this will solve this problem and you can add some padding for an inner gap of the div.

Answer (score -1):

I have reformated code. The space between box was because of default browser styles. to override you have to initialize margin and padding to 0. i have made the menu responsive. see if this solves your problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.title-container {
  border-bottom: 1px lightgray solid;
}

.title h3 {
  color: #d35400;
  font-size: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.title p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
}

.menu-items {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 1rem);
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2);
}

img {
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.item-details {
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.item-name,
.item-description {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.item-name {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.item-description {
  font-style: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
  .menu {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .item {
    height: fit-content;
    width: calc(100%-1rem);
    margin: 0;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    ;
  }
  .item-name,
  .item-description {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .item-details {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .menu {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .item {
    height: fit-content;
    width: calc(100%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="title-container">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse ratione enim ullam libero? Cupiditate voluptatum natus qui doloribus quae accusamus!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-items">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://photos.bigoven.com/recipe/hero/baked-potato-pizza-8.jpg?h=500&w=500" alt="">
        <div class="item-details">
          <a href="" class="item-name">Potato</a>
          <a href="" class="item-description">Includes potato, tomato,<br> cheese.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://photos.bigoven.com/recipe/hero/baked-potato-pizza-8.jpg?h=500&w=500" alt="">
        <div class="item-details">
          <a href="" class="item-name">Potato</a>
          <a href="" class="item-description">Includes potato, tomato,<br> cheese.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://photos.bigoven.com/recipe/hero/baked-potato-pizza-8.jpg?h=500&w=500" alt="">
        <div class="item-details">
          <a href="" class="item-name">Potato</a>
          <a href="" class="item-description">Includes potato, tomato,<br> cheese.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://photos.bigoven.com/recipe/hero/baked-potato-pizza-8.jpg?h=500&w=500" alt="">
        <div class="item-details">
          <a href="" class="item-name">Potato</a>
          <a href="" class="item-description">Includes potato, tomato,<br> cheese.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, add this CSS code

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
section {
    background: #eee;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 100px;
}
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}
.green {
    background: lightgreen;
}
.blue {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="green">Width: 50%</div>
    <div class="blue">Width: 50%</div>
</section>
```

Read this

[https://uxengineer.com/inline-block-elements-100-percent-width/]